# Why was notebook converted to single input cell upon saving?

Tags: notebooks

I recently opened a notebook of mine and discovered all the various cells (input output, headings, graphics etc) had been converted into one big input cell, complete with date, time etc for each line. I show one line here:

> 12/17/15 16:58:02 In[378]:= ImageChannels[%]

After laboriously recreating the notebook by cutting, pasting, styling, and after working with it successfully for a while, I saved it and quit mathematica. When I reopened it, the same problem had returned!
Why did this happen and how can it be avoided?

Comment: I've never encountered this before but please provide details of what version of Mathematica and your operating system

Comment: This is not the first question about that.

Comment: Mathematica 10.3, Apple OSX 10.11.1.

Comment: When I opened the corrupt file in a text editor, there was none of the usual header lines such as (* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *), only text. I have been able to cut and paste the content into a brand new notebook and all is well.